# Detect "Ubuntu on Windows" vs native Ubuntu from bash script

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Can a bash script detect if it's running in "Ubuntu on Windows" vs native Ubuntu? If so, how?

I ran `env` on both machines and didn't see any obvious environmental variable differences. I could test for the existence of the `/mnt/c` directory, but that is not foolproof because that directory could potentially also be present on native Ubuntu.

Comment: What does 'uname -a' report?

Comment: `uname -a` output from Ubuntu on Windows: `Linux COMPUTER 3.4.0+ #1 PREEMPT Thu Aug 1 17:06:05 CST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/423 answers the question, `/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease` is a string from the kernel, so it doesn't depends on the distro and the most reliable way.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It looks like `/proc/version` in Ubuntu on Windows contains:

> `Linux version 3.4.0-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com) (gcc version 4.7 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014`

and my version of Ubuntu has:

> `Linux version 4.4.0-31-generic (buildd@lgw01-16) (gcc version 5.3.1 20160413 (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) ) #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016`

This code is working for me to detect which version of Ubuntu the script is running on:

```
if grep -qi microsoft /proc/version; then
  echo "Ubuntu on Windows"
else
  echo "native Linux"
fi
```

Comment: [From an official source](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/423#issuecomment-221627364): Searching `/proc/version` or `/proc/sys/kernel/osrelease` for the strings `"Microsoft"` or `"WSL"` is the best way to do this.

Comment: `if [[ "$(< /proc/sys/kernel/osrelease)" == *Microsoft ]]; then ... else ... fi` is faster since it avoids spawning a `grep` process

Comment: @NiklasHolm You are wrong. `$(...)` spawns process. Use `read var </proc/sys/kernel/osrelease` and then check against `var` value.

Comment: @gavenkoa I didn't say it doesn't spawn a process, but it is faster than spawning grep.

Comment: @NiklasHolm There is a trick with `read var` to avoid process spawning,

Comment: This one worked on WSL 1. On WSL 2 it's lowercase microsoft. So I just used `if grep -q icrosoft /proc/version; then`

Comment: Try  `grep -qi microsoft /proc/version` to detect the spuriously cased "[M|m]icrosoft"

Comment: `if [[ "$(</proc/sys/kernel/osrelease)" == *microsoft* ]];then echo 'WSL enabled';fi` or `if [[ "$(</proc/version)" == *microsoft* ]];then echo 'WSL enabled';fi` work for me