# Recommended way of testing if I'm currently running under WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to test from shell (in a predictable way) if I'm currently running under WSL. How should I go about doing this?

This is what `uname -v` returns on Windows Anniversary update: `#1 PREEMPT Thu Aug 1 17:06:05 CST 2013`

I wonder what `PREEMPT` is. Should I use this?

EDIT: No, `PREEMPT` seems to be unrelated to WSL

EDIT 2: A bad hack would be: `$(ps auxww  | grep root | grep -v grep | wc -l) -lt $ASMALLNUMBER`

Comment: `PREEMPT` is a flag coming from the kernel, meaning that it supports preemption. You can't rely on this.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859145/detect-ubuntu-on-windows-vs-native-ubuntu-from-bash-script

Comment: @Darren Thank you. I've voted to close this.

Comment: I's suggest the *recommended* way is: don't. It shouldn't need any special handling; why do you want to know? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I have a single version of rc/config files for all my unix instances- I need to start zsh as soon as bash starts if currently running under wsl