# Bash detect WSL

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

In my `~/.bashrc` I detect running platform with `OSTYPE` (it can be `cygwin` for instance).

How should I detect WSL in Bash? Previously I used `COMSPEC` env var but it is missing inside WSL...

I prefer lightweight check without spawning external processes which are not cheap in WSL/Cygwin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a program is run in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows and not just plain Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38086185/how-to-check-if-a-program-is-run-in-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-and-not-just-plain)

Comment: Also see [Detect “Ubuntu on Windows” vs native Ubuntu from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38859145/4154375).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check `/proc/version`. On my machine (Win 10 1809), it contains:

```
Linux version 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft (Microsoft@Microsoft.com) (gcc version 5.4.0 (GCC) ) #55-Microsoft Sat Oct 06 18:05:00 PST 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

uname would also be an option, i.e.

```
if [[ $(uname -r) =~ WSL ]]; then
    # WSL detected
    <run code>
fi
```

This approach will work, as the kernel version string is slightly different under WSL2, than WSL1.

```
$ uname -r
5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

Comment: I like read of `/proc/version` better because there is no need for `fork()`.

Comment: This is now, for me, `4.19.128-microsoft-standard`

Comment: Doesn't work for my WSL1 as mine is `4.4.0-17763-Microsoft`